# SQL-Date-Question: How to get Yesterdays date in the following formatte

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, date

Here is What I have So Far

```
declare @Today smalldatetime
Set @Today = GETDATE()
select @Today
```

YIELDS

```
2011-03-10 13:46:00
```

What I need IS:

```
2011-03-09
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE()), 102), '.', '-')
```

`GETDATE()` returns the current date/time.

`DATEADD(dd, -1, GETDATE())` substracts one day from the current date/time.

`CONVERT(VARCHAR, @DATE, 102)` converts the date to ANSI format `yyyy.mm.dd`

and the REPLACE will replace the periods in the predefined format with hyphens as per your example.

Comment: 110 should return formatted mm-dd-yyyy in SQL http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 9):

For 2008 you can take advantage of the new [DATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) datatype:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Yesterday
```

For all versions:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()), 120) AS Yesterday
```

Obviously, the datatype returned by each method is different.

Comment: Weird... SQL docs say that format 120 includes hh:mm:ss - wrong documentation version?

Comment: @Dylan Beattie, 120 is what you say, but the cast to CHAR(10) discards the time.

Comment: @Dylan: No. By specifying `CHAR(10)` for the conversion data type, we get only the first 10 characters of the full `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss` string.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()), 110)
```

or

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS 'DATE'
```

Good reference if you ever need those codes again.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: Missed the word 'yesterday' somehow since I was just reading your example code. I added the dateadd function to my code.

Comment: no it was my fault i didn't specify in description...i am ashamed

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()), 110) AS Yesterday
```

Comment: That gives `mm-dd-yyyy`. OP is asking for `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: just use 23 as formatting parameter, like: SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE()), 23) AS Yesterday

Comment: @K Invaov: Interesting, I've never seen 23 documented anywhere before.